# Do I have to change int (index variables) to INT_PTR or size_t when a project is converted 32 bit to 64 bit with Visual Studio?

Tags: mfc, type-conversion, migration, 64-bit

I am converting my MFC project.

I have used several MFC collection classes.

By the way index, count (`GetCount` function) variables are not `int`. They are `INT_PTR` or `size_t`.

Do I have to change the data type to `INT_PTR`? (I don't like to see warning message while compiling.)

Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to see warnings you need to convert the variables to `INT_PTR` or suppress these warnings with `#pragma warning(disable : warning_number)`.

Converting everything that needs to be converted in order to get rid of the warnings can be very long if your code base if large, so suppressing the warnings with `#pragma warnings(disable...)` is the option I took when I ported a very large 32 bit codebase to 64 bit.

But anyway leaving your counters as `int` isn't really going to be a problem as long as your collections or whatever don't contain billions of objects.

Comment: Even though I don't want see warnings, I want to get comment from compiler. I'll change the counter variables. Thank you.

Comment: You cannot both silence your compiler and not silence your compiler.

Comment: @IInspectable I didn't get your comment and I'm not sure what's wrong with this answer. Could you elaborate? Maybe the wording was not so good, I slighly modified the answer, it is better now?

Comment: That was meant as a response to @Zenix-K's comment.